# Rails: Continue to save other attributes despite validation error in one of them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, delayed-job

I am using Delayed_Job to process Paperclip images retrieved from an Amazon S3 bucket.

The basic issue I am trying to resolve is to be able to save in the DB when a validation error occurred in processing the Paperclip image.

The basic code I have is the following:

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base

    after_save :queue_image_processing, if: Proc.new {|provider| provider.image_s3_key}

    has_attached_file :image, styles: {original: "1000x1000", medium: "530x530#", thumb: "300x300#"}, default_url: "/default-avatar_:style.png"

    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

    def self.process_image(id)

        provider = Provider.find(id)
        s3_image_object = S3_BUCKET.objects[provider.image_s3_key]

        begin
            provider.image = s3_image_object.public_url
            provider.image_s3_key = nil
            provider.image_started_processing_at = nil
            provider.error = false
            provider.save!
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
           logger.info "$$$$$ Record Invalid called $$$$"
           provider.image_s3_key = nil
           provider.image_started_processing_at = nil
           provider.error = true
           provider.save
        end
    end

    private

     def queue_image_processing
         Provider.delay.process_image(id)
     end
```

end

When the image is not of the correct format (e.g. because of spoofing of file extension), a Rollback is performed, the save! throws ::RecordInvalid. This is all good and the debug text in logger.info gets shown.

The problem I have is that the rest of the code in the rescue clause does not seem to be performed (i.e. those attributes are not stored in the DB).

This code is just one of the several tries I did, but my basic need is to be able to write the other attributes that did not receive a validation error in the DB. As you can see I need to be careful as I have an after_save callback and need to avoid that I run into this call back being called multiple times (and hence the condition on running this call back).

All the help greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

PS: Rails 4.0

Comment: Is the code not performed or the record not persisted? It would be worth checking that your record is not still invalid and that `save` is consequently returning false.

Comment: Yes you are right actually after reading the documentation and the example [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#errors-clear). The code is executed (I know this also because the debug string in the rescue code is displayed), but the record is still invalid. I wonder if there is a way to "reset" the validity (the guides clearly say that I cannot uses errors.clear as this will not change the validity of the object)...

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the way to do it, thanks to the handy cheat sheet on the [Different ways to set attributes in Rails](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/) by David Verhasselt.

It might not be the purest way of doing it, but hey, it works.

The way to do it is to use model.update_columns:

```
def self.process_image(id)
    provider = Provider.find(id)
    s3_image_object = S3_BUCKET.objects[provider.image_s3_key]

    begin
      provider.image_s3_key = nil
      provider.image_started_processing_at = nil
      provider.error = false
      provider.image = s3_image_object.public_url
      provider.save!
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
      logger.info "$$$$$ Record Invalid called $$$$"
      provider.update_columns(image_s3_key: nil, image_started_processing_at: nil, error: true)
    end
end
```

This has the added benefit (in my case, but might not fit all cases) that the updated_at is **not** updated, the validations are not performed and the callbacks are not called. In my case it good because the record is not updated after a user action, but rather only due to a failure.

Hope this helps others.